# Routing on Azure Function with Python FastAPI ASGI

Tags: python, azure-functions, fastapi

I have an **Azure Function** with **Python**. I am using also **FastAPI ASGI** by Anthony Shaw
https://github.com/tonybaloney/ants-azure-demos/tree/master/fastapi-functions

Now, it only works when `bindings.route` is `{*route}` in `function.json`:

```
Functions:

        api: [GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE] http://localhost:7071/{*route}
```

Now I can successfully call `http://localhost:7071/user/1` as expected.

##### Error

But if I change `bindings.route` to e.g. `/api/{*route}` or `api/{*route}`, if I call `http://localhost:7071/api/user/1` the function is not executed, instead the error:

```
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

is returned.

So somehow the routing partially worked (in other cases server returns 404). But the function is not being called anymore.

**What I am doing wrong here?**

I tried also:

```json
"route": "api/{*route}"
```

and

```py
@app.get("user/{user_id}")
```

But also without expected result (instead keep getting `{"detail":"Not Found"}`).

##### More implementation details:

`api.py`

```py
app = fastapi.FastAPI()

@app.get("/user/{user_id}")
async def get_user(user_id: int):
    fake_user = mimesis.Person()
    return {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "username": fake_user.username(),
        "firstname": fake_user.first_name(),
        "lastname": fake_user.last_name(),
    }


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

`host.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
    },

    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the root information please have a look [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/)

Setting the root_path in the FastAPI
In your `app.py` you can set the `root_path` parameter when creating your FastAPI app:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI(root_path="/api/v1")

@app.get("/app")
def read_main(request: Request):
    return {"message": "Hello World", "root_path": request.scope.get("root_path")}
```

Same issue discussion in github community [link 1](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2872)& [link 2](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/829)